# Failed to instantiate [org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver]: No default constructor found

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to integrate Spring 4 with Thymeleaf, but I got:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'templateResolver' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1648)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1470)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1311)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1403)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$255(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/628747463.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    ... 67 more
```

I found this topic: [Error creating bean with name 'templateResolver'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835390/error-creating-bean-with-name-templateresolver), but I am using Maven and I have dependencies for Thymeleaf-Spring4 and Thymeleaf itself:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring4 -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I create beans in `mvc-dispatcher-servlent.xml` like this:

```
<bean
    id="viewResolver"
    class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver"
>
</bean>
<bean
    id="templateResolver"
    class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver"
>
</bean>
<bean
    id="templateEngine"
    class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine"
    p:templateResolver-ref="templateResolver"
>
</bean>
```

Also something weird happened in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 EAP I think, because I have completion for missing `org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver`. Does anybody see mistake I make? Thank you in advance for every answer.
**I found a solution**, because resolver needs an argument in constructor, I have to create `ServletContextFactory` (as in [How to set ServletContext property for a bean in Spring XML metadata configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632529/how-to-set-servletcontext-property-for-a-bean-in-spring-xml-metadata-configurati)) and inject it to resolver's constructor:

```
<bean
    id="servletContext"
    class="beans.ServletContextFactory"
></bean>

<bean
    id="templateResolver"
    class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/templates/"
    p:suffix=".html"
    p:templateMode="HTML5"

>
    <constructor-arg ref="servletContext"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to hook in your `templateEngine` to the `viewResolver`.  Here's my working one:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/> <!-- THIS -->
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolvers">
        <set>
            <ref bean="webTemplateResolver"/>
        </set>
    </property>
    <property name="additionalDialects">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I found a solution (I updated the question), but thank you very much for your attention :)

Answer (score 10):

**Short**

Replace ThymeleafViewResolver with SpringResourceTemplateResolver:

```
<bean
    id="templateResolver"
    class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/templates/"
    p:suffix=".html"
    p:templateMode="HTML5"
>
</bean>
```

**Long**

Few days ago I had the same problem when used [Tutorial: Thymeleaf + Spring](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html), it is
a bit outdated. Solution was found at ["Thymeleaf 3 ten-minute migration guide"](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html):

> The first difference with the Thymeleaf 2 configuration is that now the recommended template resolver for Spring applications is SpringResourceTemplateResolver